# session_start() can't access /tmp directory when request comes from a mobile device

Tags: php, session, mobile

Before anyone assumes this has been solved before, please hear me out. Right on root, I have this simple PHP snippet:

```
<?PHP
session_start();
echo "My session ID is: " . session_id();
?>
```

When I navigate to it from any desktop, it's fine. When I navigate to it from any mobile device, I get:

```
Uncaught Exception: Cannot open source device in /sessionTest.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 /sessionTest.php(4): session_start()
#1 {main}

Next Exception: Cannot open source device in /sessionTest.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 /sessionTest.php(4): session_start()
#1 {main}

Next Exception: Cannot open source device in /sessionTest.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 /sessionTest.php(4): session_start()
#1 {main}

Next Exception: Cannot open source device in /sessionTest.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 /sessionTest.php(4): session_start()
#1 {main}

Next Error: Failed to create session ID: files (path: /tmp) in /sessionTest.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 /sessionTest.php(4): session_start()
#1 {main}
```

I created this little snippet of code:

```
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}
```

From desktop, I see this: PHPSESSID=xxxxxxxxxxx
From mobile, that's never set. That just confuses me more because those are headers from the http request, right? Not sure it even matters, it's just the one thing I've dug up that shows a difference between desktop and mobile.

Comment: what does _sessionTest.php_ look like?

Comment: It's the first thing in the summary:  

<?PHP
session_start();
echo "My session ID is: " . session_id();
?>

Comment: Could you add into the end of your script the code: ```<pre>
<?php
foreach(ini_get_all('session') as $k => $v) {
    echo "${k} [" . $v['local_value'] . "]\n";
}
?>
</pre>
```
  and show an output it produce?

Comment: session.auto_start [0]
session.cache_expire [180]
session.cache_limiter [nocache]
session.cookie_domain []
session.cookie_httponly [0]
session.cookie_lifetime [0]
session.cookie_path [/]
session.cookie_secure [0]
session.gc_divisor [100]
session.gc_maxlifetime [1440]
session.gc_probability [1]
session.lazy_write [1]
session.name [PHPSESSID]
session.referer_check []
session.save_handler [files]
session.save_path [/tmp]
session.serialize_handler [php]
session.sid_bits_per_character [4]
session.sid_length [32]

Comment: session.upload_progress.cleanup [1]
session.upload_progress.enabled [1]
session.upload_progress.freq [1%]
session.upload_progress.min_freq [1]
session.upload_progress.name [PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS]
session.upload_progress.prefix [upload_progress_]
session.use_cookies [1]
session.use_only_cookies [1]
session.use_strict_mode [0]
session.use_trans_sid [0]

Comment: It was too long, had to break it up